# Using paginate while fetching results by a SQL query in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate, kaminari

I have the following query in my Rails Controller:

```
SELECT CODE_VER FROM MASTERTEST WHERE DATE>= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) ORDER BY DATE DESC;
```

This query returns me results from the last 90 days. I display all these results in a table right now.

I want to show only rows from 7 days at a time in some kind of pagination. I have tried will_paginate and kaminari and also paginate_by_sql. But I haven't been successful using any of them so far.

Can someone show me the exact syntax incase of my query?

Comment: What DBM are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLite? You can do what you want without plugins, by using the `limit` and `offset` parameters to `select`. Some DBMs don't support `offset` but will have a start/end range for `limit`.

Comment: @theTinMan : I am using MySQL

Comment: MySQL's `limit` takes two parameters, `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15`.

Answer (score -1):

store the result in a variable say @result

In Controller

```
@result=SELECT CODE_VER FROM MASTERTEST WHERE DATE>= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) ORDER BY DATE DESC;

@result.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

In View, use

```
<% paginate %> # to render the value page by page
```